# While not equal statement and or differences

Tags: c++

```
while ((choice != "Wizard") && (choice != "Knight"))
```

This is the only one that worked

```
while ((choice != "Wizard") || (choice != "Knight"))

while (choice != "Wizard" || "Knight")
```

Honestly, I don't understand why using OR won't work and what difference it has when I separate them. Hoping someone can help explain.

Comment: What is the type of `choice` ?

Comment: `while (choice != "Wizard" || "Knight")` will always be `true`

Comment: it isn't the same because of operator precedence

Comment: If `choice` is equal to `"Wizard"` then of course it is not equal to `"Knight"`. The same reasoning applies if you switch the strings around. What does this mean for the resulting value?

Comment: what could be the choices?

Comment: Could you give us an exmaple what choice can be and what in connection to that the output sould be?

Comment: @Sean: He might be using a natural language "logic", as in *"while choice is not Wizard or Knight"*, which does not work in programming languages (or in any strict logical system).

Comment: Yes, I was working with a logic that goes by "if choice is not Wizard or Knight" Then "please try again and select a valid class". Forcing the user to only pick Wizard or Knight. I assumed my logic was incorrect  but I couldn't understand why.

Comment: @ChowShow "if choice is not Wizard or Knight" actually means "if choice is *neither* Wizard *nor* Knight." Or, with DeMorgan's help, "if choice is (not (Wizard OR Knight))" === "if (choice is (not Wizard) AND choice is (not Knight))".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the string `"Wizard"`:

- Does it differ from `"Wizard"`? No.
- Does it differ rom `"Knight"`? Yes.

So "different from Wizard AND different from Knight" is false (it does not differ from "Wizard"). However, "different from Wizard OR different from Knight" is true (it does differ from "Knight").

As for the third form, `choice != "Wizard" || "Knight"` is parsed as `(choice != "Wizard") || "Knight"`. `"Knight"` is a string literal and as such, it decays to a non-null pointer in most expressions. Being non-null, the pointer converts to `true`. So you're effectively asking: "`choice` differs from `"Wizard"` OR true." That is of course always true.

Comment: I thought if i'm using OR then any instance of false regardless if one is true will break out of the statement like 
  
take string `"Wizard"`
 
"different from Wizard OR different from Knight" 
(it does not differ from wizard) `False`
(it does differ from knight) `True`
But your saying even though one instance is false, since the other instance is true then the end result is `true` resulting into the loop

Because my original thought was that if any instance of `false` is in the statement it will break the loop because of OR? But that logic is wrong?

Comment: It is because While statements arent testing for false statements. They are testing for True statements. Thats why if the first statement is `false` it doesnt immediately break because it still has another instance to check that could be true. But lets say the first statement is true then it wont even test the other statement it will just begin the loop. I think saw that happening in the debugger. So conclusion while statements test for true?

Comment: @ChowShow Yes indeed, it follows natural language: "while the condition holds, do something." Such as "While you're hungry, keep eating.", or "While there's any items left, keep processing them: `while(itemsLeft()) keepProcessing();`".

Comment: @ChowShow As for your first comment: the expression doesn't care that it's inside a `while` condition. It's simple boolean logic that `false OR true` is `true`. First the expression's value is evaluated, and only then is the end result checked by `while`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to an ever-growing chain of `(choice != "...") &&`, you can instead create a container of things to test for, and see if choice is an element of that container.

```
static const std::unordered_set<std::string> options = {
    "Wizard", 
    "Knight", 
    "Rogue", 
    "Basket Weaver", 
};
while (options.count(choice) == 0)
```